# How to conduct a factor analysis on questionnaire data based on 30 items in three blocks?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, likert

I have a questionnaire with 30 questions divided into 3 blocks of 10 questions each. Each question is answered with a number 1 to 10 and then an average of them all is calculated. I need to know how much each block has contributed to the final score (and if possible - how much each question has contributed). How do I do this? I have access to R.

Comment: Do you need to know about FA, or only how to get one from `R`? If the latter, this question would be better posted on Stack Overflow. You may also find [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html) helpful. If you want to know more about factor analysis, you might find [this page](http://www.psych.cornell.edu/darlington/factor.htm) helpful. If you need more, or different information, could you give a little more detail about what you need to know?

Comment: A little bit of both, I want to know how to do it in R, and also how to analyze it correctly afterwards. I'll check  out the links you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA). You can lookup the basics on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis).

MCA is part of the R-core, in the package MASS. So I suggest you start with

```
library(MASS)
?mca
```

[Here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/mca.html) is the help page for the function `mca`.

The output of MCA is a set of ordered factors capturing the relationships between your variables. The absolute loadings  of the first factor (*i.e.* the coordinates of the projections of the variables on the first factor) says which groups of variables most heavily influence the variation.

As pointed out in the comments, MCA works with categorical and not numeric variables. This means that the ordered relationship (1 < 2 < 3 < ... < 10) will not be taken into account. How well MCA is appropriate depends on the nature of your questions. For instance, if those are binned numeric variables (*e.g.* monthly income / 1000, rounded up) then I'd say MCA is inappropriate. If these are subjective evaluations (*e.g.* "how much does it hurt?") then I would give it a try because the categories can sometimes be good to show non linear relationships between variables.

To do it in practice, in R, you would present your data in a `data.frame` of 30 columns and as many rows as you have individuals. Each column would be the answers to a question in the form of a `factor`, meaning that a 9, say, would be interpreted as the *category* 9, not the score 9.

Say that you have collected this in a `data.frame` that you call `answers` you could do the following:

```
mca_result <- mca(answers)
plot(mca_results)
```

You would have a biplot representing the individuals, the answers to the questions (as categories) and the relationship between all this expressed by spatial proximity. Two individuals close to each other on that space gave similar answers, two answers close to each other on that space were chosen by the same individuals. Similarly, an individual close to a group of answers has chosen many of them, and an answer close to a group of individuals was chosen by many of them.

MCA does not natively accomodate block design. A go-around that might be informative is to sum the **squares** of the loadings of the answers of each block on the first factor. The square of the loading is called the inertia and says how much the variation of a variable (an answer to a question) is represented in the simpler model consisting of only that factor. In R you could do it this way:

```
inertia_on_1 <- mca_results$cs[,1]^2
tapply(X=inertia_on_1, INDEX=rep(1:3, each=100), sum)
```

The part that says `INDEX=rep(1:3, each=100)` is to build an index corresponding to the variables of each block (labelled 1, 2, and 3) -- and there are 100 of each (because you have 10 categories for 10 questions).

Comment: Could you explain how MCA would help here? As I understand it, MCA usually deals with a set of categorical (most often nominal) variables, and doesn't consider blocks of variables, in its basic formulation. Moreover, it doesn't incorporate a model for measurement errors (attached to each item/variable), which FA does, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I completed the answer to address your comment to the best of my knowledge, except the part about the measurement errors. How bad is this in case the variables are subjective evaluation in which case the relative order can be more important than the value itself? Could you explain or point to relevant reading?

Comment: Thanks. I may not be clear about how to deal with *a priori* blocks: Do you suggest to run MCA separately on each block? Of course, there's plenty of literature on scoring categorical variables (look for optimal scaling on this site) in combination with MCA or other multivariate techniques, and on the analysis of multiple blocks. Assuming blocks are well-defined unidimensional constructs, factor analysis or structural equation modeling would provide the desired information. With separate MCAs, we would loose part of that information (relative contribution of each block).

Comment: For exactly the reason you put forward, I would do a single MCA, and then sum the contributions (intertias) of the variables per block. This is what the lines of R I propose should do. Since there are the same number of questions per block these numbers are directly comparable. But this is an _ad hoc_ trick, I am not sure it follows any "good practice".

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to calculate first principal component in each of the three blocks, and then perform a regression with your final score as the response variable and those three block scores as the explanatory variables.  This seems to me one way to answer your question of how much each block contributes to variance in the final score.

You could do the same basic approach at the individual question level too, by skipping the principal components part.

Some very skimpy R code to do the Block approach is pasted below.  This skips all sorts of things like diagnostic checks, plotting the data, looking to see how much variance within each block the first principal component explains, etc.

Also be warned - even with completely random data, one of the blocks will be more strongly linked to the final score - you need to think carefully about how to interpret that!

```
# simulate random data
x <- matrix(sample(1:10, 3000, replace=TRUE), nrow=100)

# create score as you say it is calculated
score <- apply(x,1, mean) 

# estimate a score for the principal component of each block
BlockA <-predict(princomp(x[,1:10]))[,1]
BlockB <-predict(princomp(x[,11:20]))[,1]
BlockC <-predict(princomp(x[,21:30]))[,1]

# fit a model
summary(lm(score ~ BlockA + BlockB + BlockC))
```